# ansible passing to a mapped variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template, ansible-role

I have an ansible tomcat role

defaults/main.yml

```
tomcat_http:
  port: "8080"
  protocol: "HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout: "120000"
  URIEncoding: "UTF-8"
```

I have another role (app) which uses tomcat role as a dependency and looks like below

defaults/main.yml

```
app_uriencoding: "ISO-8859-1"
```

meta/main.yml

```
dependencies:
  - { role: common, tags: app }
  - { role: tomcat, tomcat_http.URIEncoding: "{{ app_uriencoding }}", tags: app }
```

When I run the app role on my targets, Im expecting the URIEncoding value defined in the app role (ISO-8859-1) to be passed to the tomcat role and override the tomcat role default value for uriencoding.

Im unable to pass a value into tomcat roles' `{{ tomcat_http.URIEncoding }}`.  Some of the options I have tried

```
tomcat_http.URIEncoding
tomcat_http[URIEncoding]
tomcat_http.["URIEncoding"]
```

Either I get syntax errors or it just doesn't work. Please let me know if anybody has any ideas on how to pass a value into a mapped variable.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this is not possible, because with default (and advised) Ansible configuration variables overrides lower-priority ones.

But there is [hash_behavior](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) option, which you can set to `merge`.

In this case, you can use:

```
- role: tomcat
  tomcat_http:
    URIEncoding: "{{ app_uriencoding }}"
  tags: app
```

This way `tomcat_http` from role's var will be merged with role's defaults. But beware, this can brake some other parts of your playbooks.

If you expect role's defaults to be overriden independently, use:

```
tomcat_http_port: "8080"
tomcat_http_protocol: "HTTP/1.1"
tomcat_http_connectionTimeout: "120000"
tomcat_http_URIEncoding: "UTF-8"
```